# WebSocket Upgrade failed with a bad request (400) using azure.cognitiveservices.speech

Tags: azure, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

any method i use to use the Speech-To-Text service from Microsoft fails me giving me as error:

```
Speech Recognition canceled: CancellationReason.Error
Error details: WebSocket Upgrade failed with a bad request (400). Please check the language name and endpoint id (if used) are correctly associated with the provided subscription key.
```

I have been using this library for days and out of nowhere it started giving me this problem. The access data are correct. The only thing I managed to understand is that the problem occurs only when I use one of these two methods:

```
speech_config.speech_recognition_language = "en_EN"
speech_config.endpoint_id = "my_endpoint_uri"
```

Has anyone run into my own problem and know how to fix it? 
Thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: seems that "en_EN" is not valid

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to the list of supported languages in the doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/language-support?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365).

There are several locales for english, but no `EN`. You should use `en-US`, `en-GB` (or another one) depending on your needs.

For `endpoint_id` field, it should be empty if you do not use "custom" speech, or have your deployment id if you use your own custom speech

Comment: I'm trying to use "it_IT".I have read the list of languages ​​supported by the documentation and the Italian language seems to be supported. As far as the endpoint is concerned, not setting it does not solve the problem anyway.

Comment: I found the problem. I'm using the underscore instead of the hiphn

Comment: Yes, that's why it's better to add your real implementation in your question